# How do I get a firestore collection document from a user Id

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm brand new to dart/flutter/firebase and having trouble figuring out how to get collection data from firestore. The following says an invalid collection path.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class UserProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['first_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: print out documentId and make sure its not null. otherwise it looks fine to me. next thing i would check is your firebase firestore and make sure there is a collection names 'users' where it should be

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your comment Aaron. It was the firestore security rules blocking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it was incorrect firestore security rules, so this code is correct.